# Function for binary string to decimal

Tags: java, binary

I have converted a decimal number to binary using

```
int k=8;
String toBinaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(k);
```

After some manipulation I want the int value back. Can anyone help me with the function or do I have to convert it using loops only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
int originalValue = Integer.parseInt(toBinaryString , 2));
```